# mysql str_to_date warning does not show the row number

Tags: mysql

I'm importing data from .csv file to Mysql db using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" query. .csv contains foll:

```
ID | Name | Date | Price

 1. 01 | abc  | 13-02-2013 | 1500
 2. 02 | nbd  | blahblahbl | 1000
 3. 03 | kgj  | 11-02-2012 | 3444
```

My Mysql Table contains following columns:

```
Id INTEGER 
NAME Varchat(100)
InsertionTimeStamp Date
Price INTEGER
```

MySQL query to load .csv data to the table above :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'UserDetails.csv' INTO TABLE userdetails
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
 (Id,Name,InsertionTimeStamp,Price)
 set InsertionTimeStamp = str_to_date(@d,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

The above query shows warning as 
`"Incorrect datetime value : 'blahblahbl' for function str_to_date"`

where as if I remove the `set InsertionTimeStamp = str_to_date(@d,'%d-%m-%Y');`from the query, the warning message includes the row number in the below :

```
Data truncated for column 'Date' at row 2
```

Why is the warning message not including the Row Number when I use

```
set InsertionTimeStamp = str_to_date(@d,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

I want to capture the row number.